# Binding to Slider value inside HeaderTemplate in Style

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have made a style for a `Slider` where I customize the `HeaderTemplate` like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Slider">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" Grid.Column="1" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The binding of the Header-property works fine and shows up in the `TextBlock` with the `{Binding}`. But I want the `Value` property of the `Slider` to show up in the second `TextBlock`, but I can't find a way to do that. I have tried with `TemplatedParent` as source, but that crashes because it tries to get the `Value` property on a object of `ContentPresenter` type.

How can I bind the `Value` property of the `Slider` to the second `TextBlock`?

Comment: I would create a quick ViewModel with Slider Value property and Bind to that. I dont think ElementName will work in this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HeaderTemplate gets only the contents of the Header to play with. It can't see the other properties on the Slider. Since it sounds like you're aiming for a specific constant look, do you need to use the HeaderTemplate? If you embed your Header in the Slider's template then it can access the Value via RelativeSource.

Right click on the Slider and choose Edit Template.Edit a Copy... to get a copy of the Slider's template. In the template find the HeaderContentPresenter and replace it with your Grid template:

```
<!--<ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"  Foreground="{ThemeResource SliderHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}" FontWeight="{ThemeResource SliderHeaderThemeFontWeight}" Margin="{ThemeResource SliderHeaderThemeMargin}"/>-->

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Header}" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Value}"  Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

If you want to allow further customization of the Header you can use the ContentPresenter instead of the Path=Header TextBlock.

Comment: That works, thanks! I think it seems a bit overkill, that I need to have a whole copy of the template, but I guess that is needed? Is there no way to only replace the `HeaderContentPresenter`, without having all the visual state code etc.?